# What is my Android Virtual MIDI setup missing?

Tags: android, midi

I'm trying to support virtual MIDI in two of my Android apps, but opening one app's ports from the other app always fails (`openInputPort` and `openOutputPort` return null).

I'm using the native Android MIDI framework and testing on a Samsung tablet with Android 12. My apps contain the same MIDI code, so I can run them both in debug mode to test both sides of the connection. Although both apps can be servers or clients, I'm using one as a server and one as a client for testing.

In both apps, I've registered the virtual MIDI service in the `AndroidManifest` file, added the xml file to define the ports, and created a subclass of `MidiDeviceService`, as shown in "Creating a MIDI Virtual Device Service" on this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDevice

When I run the server app, `onGetInputPortReceivers` in the `MidiDeviceService` subclass is called and returns the receiver as expected. But `onDeviceStatusChanged` is not called in the server app when I try connecting to it from the client app.

In the client app, the `MidiManager.devices` includes the server app and shows its input and output ports as expected. For example:

`MidiDeviceInfo[mType=2,mInputPortCount=1,mOutputPortCount=1,mProperties=Bundle[{manufacturer=Arlomedia, product=Set List Maker, service_info=ServiceInfo{31d7c8d com.arlomedia.setlistmaker.helpers.VirtualMidiService}}],mIsPrivate=false`

However, `onDeviceStatusChanged` is never called for the server app by the `MidiManager.DeviceCallback` on the client app; it is called for USB or Bluetooth devices. And `onDeviceStatusChanged` is never called in the `MidiDeviceService` on the server app.

In other words, `MidiManager` in the client app sees the server app and its ports, but they don't trigger `onDeviceStatusChanged` like real devices, and connecting to the ports always fails.

I've only found one other Android app that creates virtual MIDI ports that I can test with. It seems that my client app is connecting to that, so that suggests the problem is with my setup of the virtual MIDI server. Do I need to do something else to activate it so clients can connect to it?